# Composition of functions is constant

Tags: functions, derivatives

If $g(f(x)):\mathcal{R}\to \mathcal{R}$ is constant. I wonder if $f(g(x))$ must also be constant? I think the answer is yes since we can take the derivative to see the derivative of either $f$ or $g$ or both is $0$. However, the answer says no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is indeed "no", even if the functions are differentiable! Consider, for example,
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \begin{cases} x^2 & \text{if } x \ge 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x < 0\end{cases} \\
g(x) &= \begin{cases} x^2 & \text{if } x \le 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x > 0.\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then $f(x) \ge 0$ and $g(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$, hence
$$(f \circ g)(x) = (g(x))^2 = \begin{cases} x^4 & \text{if } x \le 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x > 0.\end{cases},$$
whereas
$$(g \circ f)(x) = 0,$$
as $f(x) \ge 0$, so $g(f(x))$ is $0$ by definition of $g$.

You can also check that both functions are differentiable. The only point of contention is $x = 0$ for both functions, and the left and right derivatives agree.